# 3d collision in Python

Tags: python, 3d

I'm attempting to create a solid 3d box in python to act as a wall, however, the boundaries of the box extend past where the box is. As in, an invisible line continues past the edge of the box that acts as solid as the actual box. Here's the relevant snippet to the boundary drawing for collision:

```
    for i in range(len(self.walls)):
        wall = self.walls[i]
        xRad = wall.pos.x / 2 - 0.5
        zRad = wall.pos.z / 2 - 0.5
        
        if (self.camera.eye.x <= wall.pos.x + xRad):
            self.camera.eye.x = wall.pos.x + xRad
        if (self.camera.eye.x <= wall.pos.x - xRad):
            self.camera.eye.x = wall.pos.x - xRad
        if (self.camera.eye.z <= wall.pos.z + zRad):
            self.camera.eye.z = wall.pos.z + zRad
        if (self.camera.eye.z <= wall.pos.z - zRad):
            self.camera.eye.z = wall.pos.z - zRad
```

What do I need to do to confine the boundaries to the actual edges of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Your boundry conditions are likely wrong:

```py
for i in range(len(self.walls)):
    wall = self.walls[i]
    xRad = wall.pos.x / 2 - 0.5
    zRad = wall.pos.z / 2 - 0.5
            
    if (self.camera.eye.x >= wall.pos.x + xRad):
        self.camera.eye.x = wall.pos.x + xRad
    if (self.camera.eye.x <= wall.pos.x - xRad):
        self.camera.eye.x = wall.pos.x - xRad
    if (self.camera.eye.z >= wall.pos.z + zRad):
        self.camera.eye.z = wall.pos.z + zRad
    if (self.camera.eye.z <= wall.pos.z - zRad):
        self.camera.eye.z = wall.pos.z - zRad
```